# Where to store private keys in public/private key encryption in PHP?

Tags: php, encryption, private-key

I am currently developing an LMS for a school. I want to encrypt the grades students get so that only school administrators, teachers, and the student can access the grades. I don't want to be able to see the grades, and I don't want someone who somehow gets access to the database to see the grades either.

Here's how I'm thinking I'll store the grades in a database, but I'm not 100% sure if this is good or the best it can be.

1. Every user (teacher, admin, student) has a public and private key
2. Teacher grades an assignment
3. The grade gets encrypted with multiple public keys (every teacher and administrator's keys, as well as the student's) and then gets stored in a MySQL database
4. When a teacher, admin, or the student visits a page to see the grade, the grade gets decrypted with that user's private key.
5. The private key could be stored in the database, encrypted by the user's password. When a user logs in (with their password), their private key gets decrypted and then stored in a session variable (or cookie) for use during their session to decrypt the grade(s).

One thing that (I think) makes this hard is that there will inevitably be staff changes (a new administrator, a teacher gets replaced, etc.) and I need *all* teachers and administrators to have access to *all* grades. So how would I allow a new key pair to access the encrypted data when a new user account should have access?

Comment: Strongly suggest you invest in database security (don't let it get taken) rather than a non-standard encryption approach.  Secret key encryption for sensitive data is possible so that someone needs access to the key+data to get the data, but it also makes your DBA hate you (and your future self hate you too).

Comment: One other comment.  It doesn't matter how awesome your unbreakable quantum encryption is... if you are decrpyting it to show to a user, then you have unencrypted data.  An attacker just needs to focus there.  **That** is why you need end-to-end security in the web app, which takes a lot of dicipline.